# Valor Mínimo/Máximo en columnas de una List<> en c#

Tags: c#, lista

Imaginad que tenemos una lista tal que así:

```
public class hola
{
    public DateTime FECHA { get; set; }
    public int NUMERO{ get; set; }
}
```

En dicha lista voy almacenando valores de tal manera que, si los visualizamos en un `DataGridView` (por ejemplo), se verían 2 columnas: FECHA - NUMERO:

```
11/03/2019  2350
12/03/2019  1719
13/03/2019  2009
14/03/2019  1381
15/03/2019  1707
18/03/2019  1995
19/03/2019  1173
20/03/2019  1302
21/03/2019  2105
22/03/2019  580
25/03/2019  1509
26/03/2019  2165
27/03/2019  1341
28/03/2019  2003
29/03/2019  1800
01/04/2019  2262
02/04/2019  1327
```

Mi pregunta es: ¿cómo puedo conseguir el valor mínimo/máximo de los 5 últimos valores de la columna NUMERO? (estos serían: `1327`, `2262`, `1800`, `2003` y `1341`)

Gracias por vuestra ayuda.

Comment: ¿Que es lo que haz intentado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta claro que usaras `linq` en ese caso seria

```
var ultimos5 = lista.OrderByDescending(x=> x.FECHA).Take(5);

var maximo = ultimos5.Max(x=> x.NUMERO);
var minimo= ultimos5.Min(x=> x.NUMERO);
```

Primero debes orderar por la fecha para que aparezcan al principio de la lista esos 5 valores que tomaras.
De esa lista reducida tomas el Max() y Min()

[Max (LINQ)](http://www.csharp-examples.net/linq-max/)

[Min (LINQ)](http://www.csharp-examples.net/linq-min/)

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Leandro. Código sencillo pero efectivo...

Answer (score 4):

Para solucionar tu problema, bastaría con ordenarla con el criterio que necesites y luego tomes los primeros 5 elementos.

Con [`System.Linq`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq?view=netframework-4.7.2) es muy sencillo.

Asumamos que tu lista se llama `ListaDgv`

Si quisieses tomar los 5 primeros elementos en su órden original, podrías hacerlo  utilizando [`Enumerable.Take`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take?view=netframework-4.7.2) de la siguiente manera:

```
var Resultado = ListaDgv.Take(5);
```

Si lo quisieses de modo inverso (como planteas en la pregunta), bastaría con usar [`Enumerable.Reverse`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.reverse?view=netframework-4.7.2) y luego tomar los primeros 5.

```
//ADVERTENCIA, REVERSE MODIFICA LA LISTA ORIGINAL
ListaDgv.Reverse();
//Luego tomamos los 5 de nuevo..
var Resultado = ListaDgv.Take(5);
```

En caso de ser necesario, podrías también ordenarlos bajo el criterio que necesites, para luego, nuevamente, usando `Take(5)` tomar los primeros, o los últimos 5.

Por ejemplo, si ordenásemos de modo ascendente por `FECHA`

```
var Resultado = ListaDgv.OrderBy(x => x.FECHA).Take(5);
```

O de modo descendente..

```
var Resultado = ListaDgv.OrderByDescending(x => x.FECHA).Take(5);
```

Ya teniendo los últimos 5 números que necesitas, bastaría con usar la función [`Enumerable.Max`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.max?view=netframework-4.7.2) o [`Enumerable.Min`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.min?view=netframework-4.7.2) para obtener el máximo o mínimo en cuestión.

Por ejemplo:

```
var mayor = Resultado.Max(x => x.NUMERO);
var menor = Resultado.Min(x => x.NUMERO);
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Juan. Ha funcionado a la perfección...

Comment: @BenitoCatarro si esta respuesta te ha ayudado, considera marcarla como aceptada. Un saludo.